# How to upload the content of a directory in Shiny R?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a directory with different txt files. I can use the following code in my ui.R to get the files individually:
 fileInput("file", '', multiple=TRUE, accept = c("summary.txt","progress.txt")), 
However, I would like to allow the user of my Shiny app to only select the directory path that contain the summary.txt and progress.txt files. Ideally, the app should automatically get access to the content of the directory and upload its content. 
I'd appreciate it if someone can help me with this.

Comment: I doubt you can get fileInput to work that way. You can let users select multiple files with fileInput or you can use a textInput where people can copy the path to the folder.